# Upgrading a Grails app from 1.3.7 to Java 8 compatibility version

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am looking to upgrade Grails from 1.3.7.
Which version of grails is compatible with Java8?
What versions of hibernate and tomcat plugins to be used?

Answer (score 3):

> Which version of grails is compatible with Java8?

Grails 2.5.x is the first version of Grails for which we officially support Java 8.

> What versions of hibernate and tomcat plugins to be used?

Your options there will depend on which version of Grails you decide to use.  If you are using Grails 2.5.6 then I would suggest `:tomcat:7.0.70` and either `:hibernate4:4.3.10` or `:hibernate:3.6.10.18`.  With Grails 3 you have a wider array of options.

Comment: hi jeff, I have 1.3.7 grails app with java 1.6. I wanted to upgrade the jQuery plugin which is currently at 1.4.4 to make use of jQuery3.0 due to some other dependent component.  Is there any direct dependency of jQuery 3.0 with grails version and java?  If so can you please tell me which is the minimum version that I need to use for grails and java in order to support jQuery 3.0?

Comment: "Is there any direct dependency of jQuery 3.0 with grails version and java?" - There is not.  You can pull in any version of jQuery you like, or any other javascript library.  Even if you are using a JS library that doesn't have a corresponding Grails plugin that isn't a giant deal.

Comment: @ChintuKarthi I see you have asked the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446765/minimum-version-of-grails-and-java-needed-for-supporting-jquery3-0.  I left an answer there too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Which version of grails is compatible with Java8?

I upgraded to 2.3.10 with JDK 1.8 successfully in two steps.

- I first tried to upgrade it to version 2.0.5 from 1.3.7. (Note earlier vesions of grails support upgrade command which helps to upgrade few things automatically).

  Remember there will be some changes in Application

  1. AppplicationContext.xml will have some changes.
  2. The class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder is deprecated. Use below code

     ```
     def config = Holders.config
     ```
- In second step I migrated from version 2.0.5 to 2.3.10

#### What versions of hibernate and tomcat plugins to be used?

```
 runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.16' // ':hibernate4:4.3.5.4' for Hibernate 4
 build ':tomcat:7.0.54'
```