# minimum version of grails and java needed for supporting jQuery3.0

Tags: java, jquery, grails

I have a grails app using version 1.3.7 and I wanted to uplift it to jQuery 3.0 currently it's using the 1.4.4 grails-jquery plugin and java 1.6

Is there any version dependency for grails and java while updating the jQuery to 3.0? I can see grails 4.0 requires java-8. But wanted to make sure that nothing breaks as part of this upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any version dependency for grails and java while updating the
> jQuery to 3.0?

There is not.

There are no versions of Grails for which you could not use jQuery 3.  If there isn't a corresponding Grails plugin, you can still use the library.  The plugin provides some conveniences for pulling in and using a JS library but is definitely not required.